# MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification determine if song has ended

Tags: ios, mpmediaplayercontroller

When using notification center, how do you determine that the song has ended?

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                     selector:#selector(updateNowPlayingInfo),
                                                     name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification,
                                                     object: musicPlayer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nowPlayingItem should change when song has finished playing.
In conjunction with the playback state, that should be enough to determine if the song has finished playing to the end.

Answer (score 1):

In the `updateNowPlayingInfo` method check the `playbackState` property of the `MPMusicPlayerController`. If the song has ended the value will be `Stopped`. Notice that you will also have this state if the playback was stopped manually, for instance by pressing a stop button, so you will have to check for that.

Comment: that's my point.  How do you check for the end of song vs someone pressed stop.  Can't believe this is 2016 and we still don't' have a simple notification when a song has ended using MPMusicPlayerController?

Comment: Well, I assume you handle the button-press in your code. Can't you simply have a flag (a BOOL perhaps) which you set when the button is pressed. Then in `updateNowPlayingInfo` you check for that flag and if it is not set then you can assume that the song has finished.

Comment: Yeah I did that .. it just seemed to be a "hack" and didn't know if I was missing a more systematic way.